# I get unnecessary boxing to Integer in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, integer, autoboxing

My IDE gives a warning of unnecessary boxing to Integer.

```
 // Custom
 double[] Cvalues = {18,1,0,0,17};
 methodParams.put(Integer.valueOf(this.getCustom()), Cvalues);
```

Comment: Why do you need this: `Integer.valueOf(this.getCustom())`? Just use `getCustom()`.

Comment: What is the question? Are you just informing us that your IDE is telling you that you are doing unnecessary boxing. Do you think your IDE is lying to you? You are in fact doing unnecessary boxing.

Comment: my IDE is complaining about a missing semicolon. Duh!

Comment: @Michael it is an open source project I am working on. I never encountered that before and I was curious to know why it says so and if I should get rid of. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `Map<Integer, Object> myMap` and you do something like:

```
Map<Integer, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put(Integer.valueOf(1), "A");
myMap.put(Integer.valueOf(10), "B");
myMap.put(Integer.valueOf(13), "C");
```

then the compiler will generate warnings since the Wrapping with the Integer class is not necessary...

it will enough to do:

```
myMap.put(1, "A");
myMap.put(10, "B");
myMap.put(13, "C");
```

in your case

```
methodParams.put(Integer.valueOf(this.getCustom()), Cvalues);
```

looks like `getCustom()` method is returning an integer primitive making the boxing/wrapping of the primitive unnecessary.

just do:

```
methodParams.put(getCustom(), Cvalues);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the Java tutorial about autoboxing, it should be apparent after reading the tutorial that "Integer.valueOf(this.getCustom())" is unnecessary and just a call to "this.getCustom()" will remove the warning.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html